# $dialog injection causing error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-directive

Although this program works fine in Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1RmSI3liMKrE89f9YwFC?p=preview, When I add similar in MVC I get error about angular injector. 
More specifically in following line:

```
var app = angular.module('MainCtrl', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$dialog', function ($scope, $dialog) {
```

And error is as followed:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/unpr?p0=%24dialogProvider%20%3C-%20%24dialog v/<@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:443 dc/l.$injector<@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:36:196 c@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:34:273 dc/n.$injector<@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:36:266 c@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:34:273 d@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:35:1 g/<.instantiate@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:35:163 Pd/this.$get</<@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:67:417 K/<@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:54:40 q@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:7:363 K@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:53:405 f@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:47:243 f@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:47:243 z/<@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:46:374 cc/c/</<@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:18:279 Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:112:308 Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:113:24 cc/c/<@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:18:237 d@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:35:27 cc/c@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:18:145 cc@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:18:349 Xc@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:17:432 @http://localhost:51533/Scripts/angular.min.js:213:1 jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js:3073:1 jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js:3185:7 .ready@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js:3391:3 completed@http://localhost:51533/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js:3407:2
e/<()angular.min.js (line 92)
Rd/this.$get</<()angular.min.js (line 68)
Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply()angular.min.js (line 113)
cc/c/<()angular.min.js (line 18)
d()angular.min.js (line 35)
cc/c()angular.min.js (line 18)
cc()angular.min.js (line 18)
Xc()angular.min.js (line 17)
angular.min.js()angular.min.js (line 213)
jQuery.Callbacks/fire()jquery-2.1.1.js (line 3073)
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith()jquery-2.1.1.js (line 3185)
.ready()jquery-2.1.1.js (line 3391)
completed()jquery-2.1.1.js (line 3407)
angul
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using angular bootstrap, then the proper way to inject it is

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

not $dialog as it's undefined at this level

you also have to inject $dialog into controller

http://plnkr.co/edit/anfWml1umuH7miU4JDhM?p=preview

Comment: But it is there as well :(

Comment: Actually I am confused with this two controllers and modalinstance idea. So I wanted to use $dialog instead. Please see my plunker code.

Comment: you didn't injected dialog into controller, see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/anfWml1umuH7miU4JDhM?p=preview

Comment: Hi, somehow this code was updated by someone. Now I freezed it. But in my MVC and in current plunker I injected 'ui.bootstrap' but its not helping. Plunker is working fine. The problem is in MVC application

Comment: you have to inject $dialog into controller as well, check out plunker from my answer

Comment: Well when i click on button in you plunker it does open modal

Comment: probably you misunderstood my whole question. I asked that It works fine in plunker but showing that error in MVC application

Comment: That might be silly question, did you included bootstrap file, is it loading in network tab? maybe you can extend your question with a bit of HTML

Comment: The case is I get error exactly in line  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$dialog', function ($scope, $dialog) although  I have added this var app = angular.module('MainCtrl', ['ui.bootstrap']); and I have other bootstrap function in same page like bootstrap tabs and so on. I think its not something with bootstrap. It seems like it doesn't recognize $dialog

Comment: My guess is you don't include bootstrap JS file or you include it after your app js, please share the HTML where you include libraries

Comment: @maurycy  don't you have to include/download any files for bootstrap ui?

Comment: @LisaSolomon of course you have to include the bootstrap js itself if you want to use it